# How to reevaluate the code in an `eval-after-load`, after the library has been loaded?

Tags: load, eval-after-load

I've defined the following :

```
(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
  '(font-lock-add-keywords
    'clojure-mode `(("\\(#\\){"
                     (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                               (match-end 1)
                                               "∈")
                               nil))))))
```

Now I want to change it to :

```
(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
  '(font-lock-add-keywords
    'clojure-mode `(("\\(#\\){"
                     (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                               (match-end 1)
                                               "Ø")
                               nil))))))
```

If I just eval this expression, the `clojure-mode` buffer will not change, the "∈" is displayed and not change to "Ø", even if I run `fundamental-mode` and `clojure-mode` again.

How Can I fix this?

Comment: After evaluating the expression re-load the library `closure-mode` with `M-x load-library`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried `(load "clojure-mode")` and `(load-library "clojure-mode")`, neither works. I've also tried to switch to `fundamental-mode` and back to `clojure-mode` again, not worked. @Tobias

Comment: Sorry, what I forgot to mention: 1st) You need to remove the old keywords with `font-lock-remove-keywords` and the same args as for `font-lock-add-keywords`. 2nd) Run `font-lock-fontify-buffer` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias Is this right? : 1. `font-lock-remove-keywords` , 2. run `eval-after-load ... font-lock-add-keywords`, 3. run `(load-library 'clojure-mode)`, 4. run `font-lock-fontify-buffer`.  I do these thing in the order 1,2,3,4. but nothing changed. :(  (I've also tried to change the order of 3 and 4, and tried to add `font-lock-remove-keyword`, but neither works.)